# MySQL Version 5.5 syntax errors when importing sql file

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to import sql file to my database.
the query is :

```
CREATE TABLE 'project' (
  `id`              int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`            varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description`     text NOT NULL,
  `creat_time`      datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id`  int DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time`     datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user_id`  INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**The error information is :**

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''project' ( `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `name` varchar(25' at line 1)

But I did not see any errors from my query. Anyone can give me advises?

Comment: `create_time` would be better than `creat_time`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the singlequotes ( ' )  around table name ( 'project' ):

```
CREATE TABLE project (
  `id`              int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name`            varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description`     text NOT NULL,
  `creat_time`      datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `create_user_id`  int DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_time`     datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `update_user_id`  INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

<kbd>[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e1d16)</kbd>

Single quotes are used for string values. There you can use ` backticks if you want, but you might as well don't use anything.